# Simple MultiThreads program wrong output

Tags: java, multithreading

I made this simple thread substraction program.
It works fine but at the end of output it gives 3 random values. I have no idea how to prevent that, any ideas?
I also have to count how many times each thread decreased my counter. Could someone help me with this?

```
public class ThreadsExample implements Runnable {
    static int counter = 100000; 

    static long time;
    static long endtime;
    static float finaltime;
    static int value;

    static void incrementCounter() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + counter);
        counter--;    
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {    
    time = System.nanoTime();
        while (counter >= 0) {
            incrementCounter();
        }
        endtime = System.nanoTime() - time;
        finaltime = endtime;

        System.out.println(finaltime / 1000000000 + "  sekundy");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadsExample threads = new ThreadsExample();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(threads);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(threads);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(threads);
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(threads);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();

        if (counter <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1,2,3,4^^^");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you are passing the same instance of ThreadExample to each of your threads. This will likely cause some internal state abnormalities. Try creating a new ThreadsExample for each of your Thread constructors. It also looks like each ThreadsExample is going to stop at essentially the same time since "counter" is static, and all instances will detect `counter < 0` at essentially the same exact time. Is this expected? Or do you want to have each thread manage its own independent counter?

Comment: You have no form of synchronization. Therefore, each thread may read some value `> 0` and decrease the `counter`, so that the `counter` ends up with some value `< 0`. Furthermore, each thread will the `finaltime` to a value, you have a race condition there.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the pitfalls of multi-threaded programming.
There are likely two issues you are encountering.

1. You didn't declare `counter` as volatile, so threads accessing it might not see it's current value right away
2. You are not making an atomic update based on the condition (i.e. counter >= 0).
   Your check `counter >= 0` for thread 1 could be true, then thread 2 decrements counter, then thread 1 decrements it too, because it believes that counter >= 0.

Check out `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.
You might want to use it as `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, try making a few adjustments like this:

```
// Need to import Lock to protect synchronized logic
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadsExample implements Runnable {

    static int counter = 100000;
    // Lock to help synchronize access to counter
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    // These should not be static - they should be local to each ThreadsExample
    long time;
    long endtime;
    float finaltime;
    // Didn't see where this was used, so I'm using to track mod count
    int value;

    // Doesn't need to be static
    void incrementCounter() {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + counter);
        counter--;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        time = System.nanoTime();
        // Use this boolean to determine when to stop
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            // Acquire the lock
            lock.lock();
            try {
                // Now that this thread owns the lock, it can check
                // the counter without worrying about other threads
                // making modifications
                if (counter > 0) {
                    incrementCounter();
                    // Increment the mod count (how many times this thread affected counter)
                    value++;
                } else {
                    // We can stop here since counter is 0 or less
                    done = true;
                }
            } finally {
                // Release the lock so other threads have a chance
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        endtime = System.nanoTime() - time;
        finaltime = endtime;

        System.out.println(finaltime / 1000000000 + "  sekundy");
        // Print out the mod count
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updated counter " + value + " times.");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create a new ThreadsExample for each Thread
        // And give the threads readable names.
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-2");
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-3");
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-4");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();

        // Note: This will likely never get printed since it might take
        // a few milliseconds for the other threads to "consume" the counter
        if (counter <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1,2,3,4^^^");
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend giving the ThreadsExample a local name variable instead of using the Thread.currentThread().getName(), but that is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i wanted but look at the end of Console. When it reaches 0 it gives output of 3 random integers.

Comment: I don't see the 3 random integers. This is the end of my console output: 8.759564  sekundy
thread-4 updated counter 22134 times.
8.941281  sekundy
thread-1 updated counter 25116 times.
8.759831  sekundy
thread-3 updated counter 32714 times.
8.761887  sekundy
thread-2 updated counter 20043 times.

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about now. The other threads hadn't completed yet and they are reporting a non-zero counter value just before the time printouts, right? I am going to try a different approach, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean, Im waiting for your response.

Comment: I updated my code in the answer so that it uses Locks instead of synchronized methods. I updated it about 6 hours ago. See if that helps, or let me know what other problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreadsExample implements Runnable {

    private static volatile int counter = 100000; // 10k
    private int counterDecrements = 0; // zero decrements

    // Doesn't need to be static, but should likely be synchronized
    private void incrementCounter() {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + counter);
       // counter--;
       // ++counterDecrements;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long startTime, endTime, timeDiff;

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (counter >= 0) {
            incrementCounter(); // thread loop
           --counter;
           ++counterDecrements;

        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeDiff = startTime - endTime; // time diffrence is how long it took.

        System.out.println((timeDiff / 1000000000) + "  sekundy");
        // Print out the mod count
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Decremented counter " + counterDecrements + " times.");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create a new ThreadsExample for each Thread
        // And give the threads readable names.
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-2");
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-3");
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadsExample(), "thread-4");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();


        if (counter == 0) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1,2,3,4^^^^");
        }
    }
}
```